# python reading file returns 0x035022B0

Tags: python

i just started using python
and i've been trying to read a file
the code doesn't return any errors but it shows this message on the
debugging screen

```
  <_csv.reader object at 0x035022B0>
```

i searched but i couldn't find any answers
i even tried other sample codes to see if the problem is in my writing 
but it returned the same message

*Note = the file is in the same directory of the project

this is my code

```
import csv

with open('nora.csv', mode='r') as CSVFile:

   read = csv.reader(CSVFile, delimiter =",")
   print(read)

   CSVFile.close()
```

thank you for your help in advance

Comment: friend ! if you haven't any idea "what returning now !" . try `print dir(read)` if include a class `help(read)`

Comment: i did but it didn't help as much , thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using pandas to read csv files - it will place the csv information in a dataframe for you.

```
import pandas as pd

#Place the csv data into a DataFrame
file = pd.read_csv("/path/to/file.csv")

print file
```

Comment: it says that pandas is unknown type

Comment: You need to install the pandas library

Comment: i added for to fix the problem , but i will install this library and try it out , it seems very helpful ,thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

i still don't know what that message meant
but i added a for loop to read instead of just adding print
and it worked

```
import csv

with open('players.csv', mode='r') as CSVFile:

  read = csv.reader(CSVFile, delimiter =",")

  for row in read :
      print(row)

  CSVFile.close()
```

thank you guys for helping <3 <3

Comment: The message, btw, is the default `__repr__` in python: <object name at memory location (hex)>. For more, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1436756/5031339